# FlatList can't scroll horizontally

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to scroll horizontal but Its never move to the second or third item.
When I'm dragging left I cant see part of the second elements.

export const Flat: React.FC = () => {

const aaa  = [{}, {}, {}]

const renderItem  = ({item, index}: any) => {

```
if(index  === 0){
  return <View style={{width:"100%", backgroundColor: "green"}}>
    <Text> asdasad </Text>
  </View>
}
else if(index  === 1){
  return <View style={{width: "100%", backgroundColor: "red"}}>
      <Text> asdasad </Text>
  </View>
}
return <View style={{width: "100%", backgroundColor: "blue"}}>
  <Text> asdasad </Text>
</View>
```

}

```
  return <View style={{flex: 1}}>
     <FlatList style={{flex: 1}}
               contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1}}
              horizontal={true}
              data={aaa}
              renderItem={renderItem}
              keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
              pagingEnabled={true}
             // bounces={false}
    />
  </View>
}
```

Comment: Please , can you share all your code in sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-q4qymyp2l6?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js or https://snack.expo.dev/ , it will be much easier to me help you with all code

Comment: it's this component (Flat) and App.tsx  which contains only   <View style={{flex: 1, }}>
          <Flat   />
    </View>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is - https://snack.expo.dev/RNeBkS7Rk , I just added  `<ScrollView horizontal>` and change yours styles : width:"100%" to width:300